# Mysql not like and able to find a record

Tags: mysql

I've a query:

```
select * from table where license='92cbb46d087' and email='email@gmail.com' and comments NOT LIKE '%0da44455%';
```

If I remove `comments` onwards it returns me 1 record. Even if I change the NOT LIKE string to anything but it is not printing a record.

What I want is find any license  matching a license and email and whose comments record does not contain specific payment id. Indeed '%0da44455%' or '%xxxyyxxysss%' or any random string does not exist in the table in `comments` column.

Comment: Please show the table and output of your query

Answer (score 2):

If `comments` column can have `NULL` values, you won't get any output from `NOT LIKE` and `LIKE` conditions.

You need to write something like this instead : 
`WHERE (ISNULL(comments,'')) NOT LIKE '%0da44455%'`

**The reason behind this is simply because these conditions don't know how to behave with null values** — *How do you compare null as something that doesn't exist with another thing that doesn't exist?*

Comment: That comment column does not have a NULL. But still it is not able to select it using NOT LIKE

Comment: Could you show your table's data? It could help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Lets use `subquery` and select case to filter out those `not like` comments.

```
select * from (select case when coalesce(comments, '') not like '%0da44455%' then 1 else 0 end as tagCom
    , * from table where license='92cbb46d087' and email='email@gmail.com') t1
where t1.tagCom = 0
```